# How to eval string as html when used within angular attributes

Tags: angular

I want angular attributes to read its value as html.

here is an example:

```
<button matTooltip="Some<br>text">Some button</button>
```

I want "Some text" to be displayed in 2 lines using this method, I dont know what do we call that feature but is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, but if you just want to have multi-lines, this is the easiest way:

```
<button 
    mat-raised-button
    matTooltip=
"Some 
text
and
even more
text like that">
  Some button
</button>
```

Just make sure that the indentation of the text for the tooltip is like you want it - play with tabs and spaces and see what suits you best. In this example the lines will be left-aligned because all lines of text in html are at the left's margin.

Comment: to be more clear its not just  about <br> i want to use all html tags, like <b>, <i> ... get it ?

Comment: As per  https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5440#issuecomment-313740211 it's not possible. You might want to try with different approach, maybe by using: https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover